# Triangle with a square in it, with the side of $2\sqrt{3}$, what's the altitude of the triangle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

We have a triangle and within is a square with the side of $2\sqrt{3}$. What's the altitude of the triangle ABC? All 3 angles in the triangle are same (60). Pic: [http://imgur.com/gallery/SAmhU7z/new](https://imgur.com/gallery/SAmhU7z/new)

Now I know the result is $2\sqrt{3}+3$, but I am a bit lost on how to get it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: draw the altitude from the top vertex to the base in that picture and take a look again

Comment: We can use trig. The length of $AK$ is $2\sqrt{3}\tan(A)$, that is, $2$. So half of the bottom is $2+\sqrt{3}$. So, trig again, height is $\sqrt{3}(2+\sqrt{3})$.

Answer (score 2):

The top  equilateral  triangle on top of the square has sides are the same as the square.  So the altitude of the small triangle $\sqrt{3}/2$ times the side of the square.  So the altitude of big triangle is  the side of the square plus $\sqrt{3}/2$ times the side of the square.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer without trigonometry, using special triangles and proportions.

The triangle angles are the same, $60º$. Therefore the triangle is equilateral.

See the smaller right triangles to the right and left of the square? You know one angle is 90º because of the square. You know another is 60º because it is a part of the larger triangle.

Because the sum of the angles of a triangle are $180º$, the smaller right triangles each have a third angle of $30º$. These are special triangles.

In a special $30-60-90$ triangle, the sides are in the proportion of $1:\sqrt{3}: 2$, where the side opposite of 60º angle is the "$\sqrt{3}$" side, the side opposite of the 30º angle is the "$1$" side and the side opposite the right angle is the "$2$" side.

We are told the square is of side length $2\sqrt{3}$. Within the special right triangle, this is opposite of the 60º angle, so it must be the "$\sqrt{3}$" side. If this is the case, then we know the side opposite the 30º angle must be the "1" side. That is to say, it must be of length $\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}=2$. (Notice how we used proportions to get that result).

Likewise, the hypotenuse must be two times the "1" side, that is to say $2·2=4$. This is the side opposite the right angle, part of the side of the larger triangle.

Now, look at the triangle above the square. The top angle of this triangle is 60º, from what we are told. The angles adjacent to the square must also be 60º, because each of those angles, the right angle within the square, and the 30º angle in the special right triangles must add to 180º (they form a line).

That means the top triangle is equilateral; all the sides are the same length, that is to say $2\sqrt{3}$. So we now know that 1 side of the larger triangle must be the hypotenuse of the smaller special triangle to the right of the square, and the side of the equilateral triangle above the square, namely $2\sqrt{3}+4$.

Note that this is the side of the larger equilateral triangle. We can find the altitude of the larger equilateral triangle using the Pythagorean theorem.

Draw the altitude of the larger triangle. We know by the Pythagorean theorem and the symmetry of the equilateral triangle that the altitude *a* and the side length *s* are related by the following formula:

$s^2 = a^2 + (\frac{s}{2})^2$

Put $s=2\sqrt{3}+4$ into the above equation and solve for *a*.